# What is the shortest path from (-2,0) to (2,0) that avoids the interior but not the circumference of a circle with a radius 1 centered at the origin

Tags: geometry

What is the shortest path from (-2,0) to (2,0) that avoids the interior but not the circumference of a circle with a radius 1 centered at the origin?

I am getting the answer $$2\sqrt{3}$$ even though the answer is $$2\sqrt{3} + π/3$$

I don't understand why, can anyone explain why that is?
Thanks

Comment: Maybe we can explain it, if you show us how you got your answer.

Comment: I was thinking I should make a 1,2,sqrt3 triangle and because sqrt 3 is the missing side, and I just multiplied the answer by two. As to the actual answer, my answer key provided me with the number without any explanation.

Comment: The problem with your solution is that the $\sqrt{3}$ side of the triangle will pass through the interior of the circle won't it?  By the way, this has nothing to do with algebraic geometry, which is a very advanced subject.  Are you taking calculus?

Comment: I'll change the tag then. I'm taking an algebra 2 trig course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I misunderstood what you had done, sorry.  You have constructed the tangent from $(-2,0)$ to the circle, and computed its length as $\sqrt{3}$ and done the same thing on the other side.  The problem is that these two segments together do no give a path from $(-2,0)$ to $(2,0)$.  You have to add in the arc of the circle joining the points of tangency.

You will have to compute the central angle subtending this arc.  To do this, you should compute the angles of the triangle you constructed, using trigonometry.  Intuitively, this is surely the shortest path, though the above discussion by no means constitutes a proof.  I suspect you are not expected to prove it, though.

In fact, if you'e taking algebra/trig I feel sure you don't have to give a proof.